# 3D PC Game on Steam where you play a muscular jester in a magical medieval world

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I was recently watching a compilation video of weird PC games, which included *Jinx*, a Europe-exclusive platforming title where you play as a jester. This suddenly reminded me of having played a game on Steam, probably 4-5 years ago, where you play as a muscular man (kind of reminiscent of The Tick) in a blue (purple?) jester outfit, including a hooded mask that covers the top half of his face (but, I think, exposing the lantern jaw) with the traditional jester dongles on the top. I think he has a female partner who's dressed in a more sexy costume, but not revealing (I remember, at the time, thinking that I really didn't want to know how much Rule 34 artwork probably existed of her despite me only running into her in a few brief cutscenes). I think I only played less than an hour of gameplay before getting distracted, and due to my membership on a few bundle sites, I have more games than I care to admit in my library, making it hard to search. The gameplay I recall involved some platforming in a medieval village, I think including moving crates into place to get over obstacles, and fighting city guards with a combination of fisticuffs and jester props. I think there was some storyline involving the jester and his companion being rebels against the king, who wanted to outlaw, or regulate, entertainment. I honestly don't remember the details of the magic involved although I think some of it involved the main character being able to poof in and out of places in the cutscenes, and to be able to summon overlarge items out of hammerspace to hit opponents with.

I did a few searches online, but I keep pulling up other jester games, like *Once Upon a Jester* and *Pandemonium*. Part of me wants to say that the character identifies as a clown, or that maybe that's the evil king's schtick, but I'm uncertain on that.

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/app/1424300

Comment: _Pandemonium_ was the first thing that came to my mind even if it doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: @shanu: More The Tick, less anime prettyboy. :-D

Comment: @Clockwork: Yeah, after seeing that it involved a jester and his female acrobat friend, I remember thinking "Wait... maybe someone did a remake?" because it was a 3D platformer rather than *Pandemonium*'s 2.5D.

Comment: Never played it so I don't know if the plot matches, but is it [Masquerade: The Baubles of Doom](https://store.steampowered.com/app/299380/Masquerade_The_Baubles_of_Doom/)? On Steam in 2016 so it fits the time you played it, and it features a strong blue man in a purple hood trying to find orbs and rescue his "beautiful enigmatic partner in crime, Comedia."

Comment: @Giter Hah! And that one is in my Steam library, so it's an extremely likely match. He's a bit more shirtless than I remembered, but that's not uncommon. Looks like the guards are indeed dressed as clowns. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: These sort of questions are not allowed on Arqade so they're being snuck through here, despite both this site and this format not being a good fit for this question.  Try [/r/TipOfMyJoystick](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick) instead.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft well, the community has decided since long time ago that ID request is on-topic here, including [game ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This sounds like [Masquerade: The Baubles of Doom](https://www.bigant.com/all-game-list/masquerade-the-baubles-of-doom/), from the Australian company [Big Ant Studios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ant_Studios). I haven't played it and can't find much info about it, but what I've found matches your description pretty well.

> ...played a game on Steam, probably 4-5 years ago

It was released [on Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/299380/Masquerade_The_Baubles_of_Doom/) in 2016, so the timeline fits.

> ...where you play as a muscular man (kind of reminiscent of The Tick) in a blue (purple?) jester outfit, including a hooded mask that covers the top half of his face (but, I think, exposing the lantern jaw) with the traditional jester dongles on the top.

The image from the steam store page features the main character Jaxx, a muscular blue man with a purple jester-ish hood covering the top of his face:

[image: Image of a muscular blue cartoon jester, with the words Masquerade: The Baubles of Doom]

> I think he has a female partner who's dressed in a more sexy costume, but not revealing

According to the Steam description Jaxx has a "beautiful enigmatic partner in crime, Comedia", who was captured. From the few images I can find, Comedia seems to be dressed in a dark blue/black hooded outfit, which isn't revealing compared to Jaxx's chest straps.

> The gameplay I recall involved some platforming in a medieval village, I think including moving crates into place to get over obstacles, and fighting city guards with a combination of fisticuffs and jester props... and to be able to summon overlarge items out of hammerspace to hit opponents with.

From the images on the Steam page, it looks like the gameplay involves platforming in a medieval setting, and fighting with an oversized hammer and comedic comic book-esque "POW!" popups.

> I think there was some storyline involving the jester and his companion being rebels against the king, who wanted to outlaw, or regulate, entertainment... Part of me wants to say that the character identifies as a clown, or that maybe that's the evil king's schtick, but I'm uncertain on that.

I can't find much info on the plot, but from the Steam description you have a map leading to powerful orbs, and that "From foreign shores came the Clowns, an army of morose maniacs determined to find the Orbs. And so began the Great Clown Invasion." So, fighting evils clowns to stop them from taking over more-or-less fits what you remember.

Comment: https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/031/568/549/large/jeff-mahadi-masq-leaderboard-assets-01.jpg?1603984871

Comment: Yeah, not very revealing but it might have more to do with the behaviour maybe.